# Enabling Video Streaming with NGINX

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I have just enabled nginx for Live Video Streaming. I followed the article (https://www.nginx.com/blog/video-streaming-for-remote-learning-with-nginx/). When I run

`sudo nginx` I am getting the warnings below

````
nginx: [warn] duplicate extension "ts", content type: "video/mp2t", previous content type: "video/mp2t" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:39
nginx: [warn] duplicate extension "html", content type: "text/html", previous content type: "text/html" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:40
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1935 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind() ```



Can someone please help me resolve this error. I have also included the config file for nginx. The article does not really give clear instructions for not so linux tech savvy people, it's missing some steps and doesn't really indicate where to put what.
````